# Is it possible to find out who fired the event, User or DOM API?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

### Context

Lets say We are on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) page and we attach a `scroll` event listener to the window.

```
document.body.addEventListener("scroll",(e)=>console.log("scroll fired"))
```

Now there are two ways to trigger the event, one is user scrolling and other one being `window.scroll(X,Y)`.

### Problem

So, is it possible to find (in event handler) whether the user, or the computer(DOM API), triggered the event?

Please pardon if I asked something lame.
Thanks!

ref-

- [window.scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)
- [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)